# Linear filter (FIR) in Hadoop (Hadoop in Action exercise)

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Exercise 4, Chapter 4 in Hadoop in Action is about implementing a linear filter computing the moving average of a time series. That is, given N and a series of timestamped values a(t), compute y, where

```
y(t) = a(t)*1/N + a(t-1)*1/N + ... + a(t-N)*1/N.
```

I'm having trouble implementing this in Mapreduce. A reducer needs to receive the N records required to compute an element in y together. Even if the records are ordered chronologically, these N records might be split across two mappers. What kind of key to emit in the mapper would guarantee that the same reducer receives these N records? Their timestamps are all different and are thus not useful as keys.

Or am I completely off in my approach? I'd be thankful for hints.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the problem from the book, you have misstated the problem a little.

The input data is a sequence of key/values (t -> x(t)), where t is a time and x(t) if the value observed at that time.  Then to compute a moving average at any time, you use the formula:

```
y(t) = a0 * x(t) + a1 * x(t-1) + a2 * x(t-2) + ... + aN * x(t-N)
```

where a0, a1, a2, ... aN are known constants.

The key to implementing a mapper for this problem is to recognize all y(t) equations that contain a particular x and using the equation as the key.  This is done by observing the patterns of the time parameter, t.  For any x(t), x(t) is in the first in y(t).  x(t) is also the second term in y(t+1), the third term in y(t+2), and so on up to the (N+1) place term in y(t+N).

So, for each for each (t -> x(t)) key/value in the input the mapper needs to output several new key/value pairs:

```
t   -> {a0, x(t)}
t+1 -> {a1, x(t)}
t+2 -> {a2, x(t)}
...
t+N -> {aN, x(t)}
```

After the mapper is complete, there will be a collection of {an, x(t)} values keyed by the y(t) equation they are part of.

On the reducer side, the set of {an, x(t)} values for a particular y(t) will be delivered for which a sum of products can be computed to produce the y(t) value.

Comment: Thanks a lot Brent, that makes sense. I won't get around to implementing it in the next few days, but I'll get back to the question.

Comment: I tried to implement this again. Brent, in your approach, isn't it necessary that the timestamps come in fixed intervals? If I encounter t and want to emit the keys t+1, t+2, ..., I need to be able to compute t+n. If that's possible, your solution works, but what if they are somewhat random, like timestamps triggered by an external event?